# Using PyMongo to make aggregate query on MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I'm writing a Python script to connect to MongoDB using PyMongo and run aggregate query.

```
import datetime, time
import sys
import traceback
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(IP, PortNo))
db = client[Dbname]
print db

startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(from_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
enddate = datetime.datetime.strptime(to_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

pipe = [{'$match':{"audit_time": {"$gt": startdate,"$lte": enddate}}},{'$group': {'_id':{'day': { '$dateToString': { 'format': "%Y-%m-%d", 'date': "$audit_time" } }, 'policy_id': '$policy_ids'},'SID': {'$sum': 1}}}]

result = db.compliance_name.aggregate(pipeline=pipe)
print result
```

Output got:

```
 Database(MongoClient('IP', 27017), u'Dbname')
 {u'ok': 1.0, u'result': [{u'SID': 1462, u'_id': {u'policy_id': [u'384509a-9ccc-4305-8678-b80b1d5795c'], u'day': u'2015-11-24'}}], u'$gleStats': {u'lastOpTime': Timestamp(0, 0), u'electionId': ObjectId('5651c922a4feda96d2e4a939')}}
```

On Mongo Shell same aggregate query gives the expected output

```
PRIMARY> db.compliance_name.aggregate([{'$match': {'audit_time': {'$lte': new Date(2015, 11, 24, 23, 59, 59), '$gt': new Date(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0)}}}, {'$group': {'SID': {'$sum': 1}, '_id': {'policy_id': '$policy_ids', 'day': {'$dateToString': {'date': '$audit_time', 'format': '%Y-%m-%d'}}}}}])
 { "_id" : { "policy_id" : [ "384509a-9ccc-4305-8678-b80b1d5795c" ], "day" : "2015-11-24" }, "SID" : 1462 }
```

Why do we get extra fields like Ok? Results and glestats when run from PyMongo. How do avoid those?

Comment: Try `db.compliance_name.aggregate(pipeline=pipe)['result']`

Comment: You cannot avoid them. Workaround is the way like @vaultah suggested

Comment: @vaultah Yes i can use this . I have another query.
When i run the script from one remote machine i get the output with result.
From another remote machine i get the output as i get in mongo shell 
{ "_id" : { "policy_id" : [ "384509a-9ccc-4305-8678-b80b1d5795c" ], "day" : "2015-11-24" }, "SID" : 1462 }.

Why 2 different outputs its very confusing

Comment: Ok got the issue. It was difference between in Pymongo version. 
Pymongo version 2.x returns the above extra fields where as Pymongo 3.0.3 returns  a cursor for aggregate query.